# Как установить конкретному View в конкретном item ListView необходимые свойства?

Tags: java, android, listview, view, cursoradaper

Есть `ListView`, кастомный адаптер от `CursorAdapter` и `Cursor`. Связка работает. Строки в `ListView` состоят из двух `TextView`.

Допустим строк в `ListView` 20. Как добраться до 15 строки, в ней к 1-ому `TextView` и изменить в нем некоторые свойства, так чтобы каждый раз при загрузке этого `ListView` именно в этом `TextView` было определенное свойство. Конкретно, устанавливаю шрифт.

В адаптере, в методах `newView` и `bindView` меняются все строки (`TextView`) сразу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В адаптере, в методах `newView` и `bindView` меняются все строки (`TextView`) сразу.

В методе `bindView(...)` Вы можете получить позицию:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    int position = cursor.getPosition();
    ...
}
```

и далее крутиться от нее.